# can Capybara use Selenium Iphone Driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to run some test on an iphone emulator, i have the iWebdriver iphone emulator running on an ip address.

Is this possible as all the google results are about updating to user agent to make it as if an iphone is being used, but i actually want to use the actual iphone emulator from selenium.

Config:

```
 Capybara.default_driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://192.168.1.12:3001/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :iphone
```

Error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit 'http://localhost:8090'
     Capybara::DriverNotFoundError:
       no driver called Selenium::WebDriver was found, available drivers: :rack_test, :selenium, :webkit, :webkit_debug
     # ./create_page.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in createpage'
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara.default_driver method accepted :rack_test, :selenium, :webkit, :webkit_debug

Try

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app,
    :browser => :remote,
    :url => "http://192.168.1.12:3001/wd/hub",
    :desired_capabilities => : iphone)
end
```